# Jenkins Job DSL: Create Maven Job which calls another Job DSL file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to create a Jenkins Job DSL which creates a Maven Project. The created Maven Project should execute another Job DSL which is in my Bitbucket Git repo. I am havin a hard time finding the right Job DSL tags/methods I need for achieving this goal. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
mavenJob('CD/cd-parent-master') {
    scm {
        git {
            remote {
                name('origin')
                url('-------')
                credentials('Bitbucket_Access')
            }
        }
    }
    description 'MavenJob which calls another Job DSL'

/* Tag which specifies that the created MavenJob should process another Job
 DSL and the location of that Job DSL on my Jenkins FileSystem.*/

    wrappers {
        mavenRelease { }
    }

    jdk('JDK 8')
    mavenInstallation('connecteddrive Maven 3')
    goals('clean deploy')
}
```

Comment: This should be possible. Have you seen https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.dsl if you cannot invoke this from a maven context the have the maven job trigger a separate job. The generate that job from your seed job and reference the above step.